# Castle Windsor Update Instance Property

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I'm trying to use Castle Windsor to reuse a single instance of my WebApp settings class (`MySettings`). 
This settings rarely changes, but when it changes, I need to update the instance in the container.
I can easily track when the Settings changes, but I can't figure out the right way to do it, can anybody help me?

The Windsor Installer class is bellow:

```
public class SettingsInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    private MySettings Settings { get; set; }

    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        UpdateSettings();

        container.Register(
            Component.For<MySettings>()
            .Instance(this.Settings));
    }

    public MySettings UpdateSettings()
    {
        using (DbContext db = new DbContext())
        {
            this.Settings = db.Settings.FirstOrDefault();
        }

        return this.Settings;
    }
}
```

How can I call the `UpdateSettings()` and make sure that the container will use the updated `Settings` in the next Dependency Injection resolution?

Comment: Did my answer below help? I think it will greatly simplify your code if it's what you're looking for :)

Comment: In your solution, I can update one setting, but I need to reload MySettings. Because my settings can be updated in the MVC CRUD. So the main question is: can I update a singleton instance?

Comment: How are you accessing MySettings in order to update it? If you're using constructor injection to pass it into your controller, then it will be the same instance every time as long as you're resolving your controller using dependency injection.

Comment: Now I can see your idea. You idea can update properties of the singleton idea indeed.
But, I don't mind updating the instance of a injected instance (Since the request is very fast). I just want the new requests, after the `MySettings` being updated, having the new updated instance

Comment: I'm not sure why you wouldn't use a singleton, but if you really need a new instance every time you can just create a new MySettings and assign it to the variable you've passed in to your constructor.

Comment: The idea of Singleton is because one instance could serve all the requests. I just need to update the Singleton for the next requests, serving the updated from database one.

Answer (score 0):

I had no answer yet. I have done this, and it is working:

```
public class SettingsInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    private static MySettings Settings { get; set; }

    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        UpdateSettings();

        container.Register(
            Component.For<MySettings>()
            .UsingFactoryMethod(() =>
            {
                return SettingsInstaller.Settings;
            })
            .LifestyleTransient());
    }

    public static MySettings UpdateSettings()
    {
        using (DbContext db = new DbContext())
        {
            SettingsInstaller.Settings = db.Settings
                .AsNoTracking()
                .FirstOrDefault();
        }

        return SettingsInstaller.Settings;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is for MySettings to be a singleton whose state you can then update in other parts of the application. If you register MySettings as a singleton, then whenever the container resolves a MySettings for you, it will return the same instance. This is essentially what you are doing in your answer, but you're just storing the instance in a local variable (instead of letting the container do it for you).

Your registration code can then get very simple:

```
public class SettingsInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
         container.Register(Component.For<MySettings>().LifestyleSingleton());
    }
}
```

Whenever you need to access the settings, you can request a MySettings from the container using constructor injection (or any other method of getting an instance from a container):

```
public class ClientClass
{
    private readonly MySettings _settings;

    public ClientClass(MySettings settings)
    {
         _settings = settings;
    }

    public void UpdateSettings()
    {
         _settings.SomeSetting = myNewSetting; // reset them however you need to here
    }
}
```

After you've called UpdateSettings() in your application somewhere, then the instance the container is holding on to (a singleton) will be updated with myNewSetting, and when the next class requests a MySettings you'll get the same instance with the updated value.

If you actually need a new instance of MySettings, then in your UpdateSettions() method you can create an entirely new one using
`_settings = new MySettings()` and the container will serve up the new instance for you from then on.